How to integrate custom Rust Programs with AMM's like Raydium and Mateora?
I am looking for same kind of question, I found the Raydium code on the Github. Have someone integrated with their smart contract (program) buy/sell? I want this?
I am also looking for the code for the Mateora Dex for their Dynamic Pools to be integrated with my custom Anchor Rust Program ?
Mateora Dynamic pool link
The github for mateora

could you show the Raydium code github address?
